# I need to fetch the data related to particular keyword in mysql query

Tags: mysql

SELECT tl_tea.*,tl_business.business_name,tl_business.sk_business_id,tl_tea_type.tea_type,tl_tea_type.sk_tea_type_id  from tl_tea LEFT JOIN tl_business  ON business_id=tl_business.sk_business_id LEFT JOIN tl_tea_type ON tl_tea_type.sk_tea_type_id=tl_tea.tea_type where tl_tea.tea_status='active' and ((tl_tea.tea_name LIKE '%$text%') ||
                    (tl_tea.tea_desc LIKE '%$text%') || (tl_business.business_name LIKE '%$text%') || (tl_tea_type.tea_type LIKE '%$text%')) limit 8 offset $offset

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: input :
brand name can be given (or) only product name can be given (or) both brand and product name can be given
here order of giving input can be anything like ( brand product ) or (product brand) or(product) or(brand)
so we need to check weather the given input is brand or product

output : if product as input only product should be displayed
    : if brand as input only brand should be displayed
  : if brand and proudct as input product related brand should be displayed

Comment: Conditions by right tables in WHERE kills LEFT JOIN converting it into INNER.